# Starting database: mongod failed

Tags: linux, mongodb

I fail to install mongodb on my server (ssh; linux-gnu). Get the following trace:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package mongodb-org-server.
(Reading database ... 73280 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (from .../mongodb-org-server_3.0.5_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (from .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.0.5_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (from .../mongodb-org-tools_3.0.5_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mongodb-org.
Unpacking mongodb-org (from .../mongodb-org_3.0.5_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.0.5) ...
Starting database: mongod failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (3.0.5) ...
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Setting up mongodb-org-tools (3.0.5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
 mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have been following instructions from [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

I tried to [repair it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473446/2069858), but it didn't help.

```
mongod --repair 
2015-08-03T09:11:28.456+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-08-03T09:11:28.456+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I was also trying to [install locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24382599/2069858), but it also didn't help.

How can I get around this and install mongodb? What can be the error?

Comment: What I ended up doing was installing binaries of mongodb, creating folder data/db with write permission for user. I also had problems with little space on the disk, so I invoke mongodb --smallfiles

Answer (score 0):

After successfully installing MongoDB (via Homebrew) on Yosemite, these instructions were displayed:

```
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Then to load mongodb now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist

Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

"*/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf*" contains the "*dbpath*" argument. After reviewing that file I was also able to start MongoDB as follows:

$ mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb

On a Linux environment your paths are probably different, but I hope this helps answer your question and provides you with some direction to solve your problem.